# what should I do when springboot throw "IllegalArgumentException" after imported open-feign

Tags: spring-boot, openfeign

I was trying to build a gateway based on microservice, and the project failed to run after I imported open-feign version 4.0.1, I didn't add any annoation related to openFeign in my project yet.
I'm using java8 and jdk1.8,springboot2.7.10, springcloud2021.0.4. I used java 21 to build this project in IDEA, and changed it to java8 in "setting" later

IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.boot.BootstrapRegistryInitializer : org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.RefreshBootstrapRegistryInitializer

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/cloud/bootstrap/RefreshBootstrapRegistryInitializer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I want to fix this problem and run open-feign services properly

Comment: don't post pictures of error messages.

Comment: The root problem here seems to be that one of your dependencies (the one that supplies RefreshootstrapRegistryInitializer) is unsuitable for your jre. That is probably a mistake in your build-process

Comment: you say: "I used java 21 to build this project in IDEA, and changed it to java8 in "setting" later" - that is probably the cause of the version mismatch. Use a build-tool, maven or gradle, when programming java, don't rely on whatever the IDE is doing (as that can probably not be exactly repeated somewhere else).

Comment: thank you so much , but Ive tried both add "<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>" and add compiler plugins in maven pom to nominate jdk version, but the error remains. Are there anything else I can do to fix this problem ?

Comment: you have a dependency that is incompatible wit your build. Try to figure out what package gives you the class mentioned above. A possible fix would be to use an older version of the package. If the package doesn't support java8 at all, you're out of look.

Comment: * I meant "out of luck", not "look", but I can't edit my comment anymore.